# CodeIgniter: Error routes login

Tags: php, codeigniter

well i'm the problem with routes.

My routes:

```
$route['assets/(:any)'] = 'assets/$1';
$route['login'] = "home/login";
$route['default_controller'] = "home";
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

when i access:  localhost/sciv/ its responding the ['default_controller'] all right here ok,so i need to do a login so my form:

```
<?php echo form_open('home/login'); ?>

        <?php echo form_label('Login:', 'login'); ?>
            <?php echo form_input("login"); ?>
        <br>

        <?php echo form_label('Senha:', 'senha'); ?>
            <?php echo form_password("senha"); ?>

        <br>

        <?php echo form_submit('entrar', 'Entrar'); ?>
```

my form go to the Controller Home and acess the Action Login, right?

```
public function index()
    {
        if($this->is_logged_in())
        {
          $data['login'] = $this->session->userdata('login');        
          $this->load->view('admin',$data['login']);
        }else
        {
          $this->load->view('login');
        }
    }

    public function login()
    {

        $this->load->model('usuario');
        $resultado = $this->usuario->validate();

        if($resultado)
        {
            $dados = array(
                    'login' => $this->input->post('login'),
                    'is_logged_in' => true
                );

            $this->session->set_userdata($dados);
            $this->index();
        }
        else
        {
            redirect('fadas');
        }


    }

    public function is_logged_in()
    {
        return $this->session->all_userdata();
    }

    public function logout()
    {
        $this->session->sess_destroy();
        $this->index();
    }

}
```

so but when i submit the form, show ERROR 404.. I guess that I can not understand routes yet :\

my htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|assets|robots\.txt)
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

My Model

```
public function validate()
        {
            $this->db->where('email', $this->input->post('login'));
            $this->db->where('senha', md5($this->input->post('senha')));
            $this->db->where('status',1);
            $query = $this->db->get('usuario');         

            if($query->num_rows == 1)
            {
                return TRUE;
            }
        }
```

My Base_url

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/sciv/';
```

Comment: just try the comment $route['login'] = "home/login"; in route file then try

Comment: i already try, commented everything leaving only  $route["default_controller"] that is work, i'm posting all my Action for you see business rule

Comment: just inspect the form and show us form tag in html

Comment: <form action="http://localhost/sciv/home/login" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">

Comment: i think you are missing RewriteBase in .htacces file

Comment: $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/sciv/';

Where's missing?

Comment: before, i had gotten do a login and go to the admin page, so for some problem i lost the session and come back to login page, so now i can not login

Comment: I started other project and worked everything '-' why this :\

Answer (score 0):

```
redirect('fadas'); // Is this defined?
```

Do you have a route defined for this? Seems like your login function is failing and control is entering else segment.

As I see, there is no route defined for fadas. 
Check on this

Comment: "fadas" is just a test, until now I have not been redirected to this link, so I presume this does not affect anything.. I will go past my Model